# How to correctly do threading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, parallel-processing

I've been studying .Net threading and have learned about the `Threading.Task` and `Threading.Task.Parallel` classes. Right now using the `ForEach` method of `Parallel` class I process each object on a separate thread. However I beleive the `ForEach` method waits for all threads to finish executing before it comes back. This results in those threads that finish before others to sit idle. I want to have these threads working constantly. So this is what I'm hoping to do:

I have thread `A` in charge of slice selecting records from the table and then starting n worker threads to process each record.

1. Every time a worker thread finishes its job, it should ask thread `A` for the next record to process.
2. When allocating records to worker threads, if thread `A` runs out, it should go back to the database and fetch some more. I'm guessing this allocating process has to be wrapped within a critical section block.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial that fits my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a producer consumer scenario you can use the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) which is already thread safe.

That means that you can fill it from any A thread, and pop out items to work on from all other consumer threads without using locking.

Answer (score 1):

What you're discussing is typically called a "thread pool". [MSDN's "How to: Use a Thread Pool"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will probably be relevant to your interests.